# IIS6 with IE8 not loading ASP.NET MVC site properly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, asp.net-mvc-2, internet-explorer-8, iis-6

This is odd, and I hope I explain it correctly.

When I debug locally with VS2008, IE8 looks like FF and Chrome (minus the obvious).  It works well, and I'm happy.

When I use IE8 with our IIS6 box (Win2003) or Cassini, buttons aren't aligned, javascript errors occur, and some other CSS anomolies occur:  Table cells missing colored borders, div elements having different dimensions by 2-3pixels.

If anyone has come across this, please let me know - It's completely baffling me

Comment: Make sure that IE8 is not in quirks mode.

Comment: Yup, Quirks mode was it!  Now, what is quirks mode and can I ensure my users will have it off by default?  thanks Ahmad!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IE8 runs in different modes depending on if it's visiting a site running on localhost vs another server.  It's weird, I know.  I've run across this issue before as well.  Use the developer tools (F12) and check which mode (Quirks, IE7 Standard, IE8 Standard, IE8 Compatibility) the browser is running in.

Comment: Seriously? Holy stupid (I know of no good reason for it, however).  So, can I guarantee my users will not see the incorrect version (quirks) when they visit the site?

Comment: I believe it has to do with the doctype declaration at the top of the HTML file.  If it is not there, or it references an invalid DTD, then the browser goes into quirksmode.

Comment: Alrighty then, fixing that immediately :P. Thanks JungleFreak!

Comment: Absolutely not a problem.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Could it be an old CSS file that is cached on the client?

Comment: I was really hoping that was it, but I cleared the cache repeatedly - same issue.

Comment: Are you using IE8 from 2 different machines, if yes check if they are the same patch level, possibly other config differences

Comment: Same machine :-/.  Keep them coming, I appreciate the help immensely!