# IE displays page differently between debug in visual studio and on the server

Tags: html, css

This is a continuation of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764609/javascript-is-not-able-to-convince-the-mouse-to-change-its-cursor/3764704#3764704) question.

I have an ASP.NET app that has some sections displaying differently when viewed in IE8 in  DEBUG vs displaying off the published TEST server location.

When I view the page in Debug (through VS 2010), I see this:

[image]

However, when I publish to the server and view it directly, it looks like this:

[image]

The title box only has the text background color as black instead of the whole section.

Here's the CSS:

```
.imageBox
{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    text-align: center;
}

.imageBoxTitle
{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #333333;
    padding: 5px;
}

.imageBoxTitleLbl
{
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: small;
    color: White;
}
```

Here's the generated HTML

```
 <div class="imageBox">
    <div class="imageBoxTitle">
        <span id="MainContent_ImagesPanel_ImageHolder1_ImageBoxTitleLabel" class="imageBoxTitleLbl">ITEM OVERVIEW</span>
    </div>

    <div class="imagePlaceHolder">
        <p class=".centeredImage"><a id="MainContent_ImagesPanel_ImageHolder1_ImageHyperLink" href="UserImages/nu5t3hhs.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="UserImages/nu5t3hhs.jpg" height="200" width="200" /></a></p>
        <span id="MainContent_ImagesPanel_ImageHolder1_CustomValidator1" style="color:Red;visibility:hidden;">*</span>
    </div>

    <div class="imageAction">  
    </div>
</div>
```

So I was thinking that this is probably some kind of caching issue. However, if I make slight changes to the CSS (e.g. change the background color) it picks that up and displays it. Also, I've added a dynamically generated GUID to the querystring for the css files, so they should never get cached. Fiddler confirms that they are not cached, too.

IE seems to render the HTML/CSS differently when viewing through Visual Studio Debug vs accessing the page directly from the server.

What things might cause this behavior?

UPDATE: When I view the page in Chrome or Firefox on the published server, it appears correctly. I have cleared the IE cache (ctrl-f5), deleted the .css off the server and reloade, etc.

Comment: IE cache ? try to refresh with Ctrl + F5, the guid is maybe not enougth.Are you sure, it's the good css file ? maybe you didn't put your updated css on the server (I want to be sure, because most of the time these problem have easy solution)

Comment: I've tried CTRL-F5, I've deleted the .css file off the server, I see in Fiddler that it's returning a 200 when it's retrieved. I've cleared the IE cache. If I view it in Chrome, it appears correctly.

Comment: Are you sure that's the full snippet, because that's invalid HTML - one of the closing `</div` is missing. Also, where's the image?

Comment: I only added the bits regarding the header. I'll add the whole section to the question

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When IE renders on **localhost**, it will use **standard compliant mode**.

However, when it renders on an **Intranet**, it will use **compatibility mode**.

Don't ask me why it does this, it's just one of those arbitrary MS things in order to spice up our developer lives.

Just add this to your header to force IE into standard compliant mode :

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 3):

Credit to JungleFreak for the complete [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3735106/26866)

> IE8 runs in different modes depending on if it's visiting a site running on localhost vs another server. It's weird, I know. I've run across this issue before as well. Use the developer tools (F12) and check which mode (Quirks, IE7 Standard, IE8 Standard, IE8 Compatibility) the browser is running in.